# Misplaced \noalign error

Tags: tables

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\ensuremath
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & Lunedì & Martedì & Mercoledì & Giovedì & Venerdì \\
\hline
8-9 & & & (8.30) P (CP) & & \\
\hline
9-10 & P (GD) & & P (CP) & & \\    
\hline
10-11 & P (GD) & D (FC) & P (CP) & & D (FC) \\
\hline
11-12 & & D (FC) & F, S, D (MS) & & P (GD), D (FC) \\  
\hline
12-13 & & D (FC) & F, S, D (MS) & & P (GD), D (FC) \\
\hline
13-14 & & & & & \\
\hline
14-15 & P (CP), F (PS) & & F (PS) & & F, S, D (MS) \\
\hline
15-16 & P (CP), F (PS) & & F (PS) & & F, S, D (MS) \\
\hline
16-17 & & D (RO) & & D (RO) & \\
\hline
17-18 & & D (RO) & & D (RO) & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
```

I've been looking for similar questions for days, but none of the ones I've found solve my problem

Comment: The culprit is `\ensuremath`. Why did you use it?

Comment: Without \ensuremath, I get ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $

Comment: With this very code???

Comment: @Bernard: I can confirm this. The error seems to be caused by the `ì` in combination with the `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and `pdflatex`. Commenting out said package (and of course `\ensuremath`) the code works perfectly fine (but yields and overfull box warning due to the table being too wide).

Comment: It seems so. I found some question about "! Missing $ inserted" solved with \ensuremath and so i put it in my code. It worked, I hope it is not really the cause of the new problem

Comment: @CarloSchianodiCola: Aparently it did not work since you effectively replace one error message by another one. Since there is nothing related to math (or anything that would need math mode) in your table, adding `\ensuremath` does definitely not help in this specific case.

Comment: @Leandris: In addition, I compiled with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (as should be nowadays) and had no compiling problem, except for the `overfull \hbox` warning too.

Comment: Are you sure your file is encoded as Latin-1?

Comment: I've just switched from [latin1] to [utf8] option and it worked (I've also got rid of the \nsuremath of course).

Comment: your document is presumably _not_ stored in lati1 (iso-8859-1) encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, let's see what happens (bullets denote a space in the macro name).

1. `\ensuremath` expands to `\protect\ensuremath•`
2. `\protect` is `\relax` in this context, so it disappears
3. `\ensuremath•` expands to `\ifmmode\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter \@ensuredmath\fi`
4. Since we're not in math mode, `\expandafter\@ensuredmath\fi` remains
5. `\expandafter` removes the `\fi` and `\@ensuredmath` remains

The definition of `\@ensuredmath` is

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 4666:
\long\def\@ensuredmath#1{$\relax#1$}
```

What's taken as argument of `\@ensuredmath`? No brace follows, the next token is `\begin`, we get

```latex
$\relax\begin$
```

Now LaTeX happily proceeds, because there *is* a macro `\$`. A long series of errors follows, but if you skip them all, you'll see that LaTeX typesets

[image]

where the $ symbol is clearly visible, generated by the `\$` produced by `\begin$`. No `tabular` environment is started, so `\hline` is completely out of place (the shown error is indeed `Misplaced \noalign` as you can check by a simple document such as

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hline
\end{document}
```

No, adding `\ensuremath` if an error `Missing $ inserted` pops up is generally the wrong thing to do. Take as general rule that `\ensuremath` should never be used in the `document` environment; it has its uses in command definitions.

The error `Missing $ inserted` should be taken care of by looking where math mode is wrongly started or unfinished.

If I remove the wrong `\ensuremath`, the example document compiles well when encoded as Latin-1.

If I encode it as UTF-8, then the `Missing $ inserted` error pops up.

Solution: your document *is* UTF-8 encoded, so change `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` into

```latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(or remove the call altogether if you're using an up-to-date TeX distribution).